# scheme higher order func

Tags: hash, lisp, scheme

Given the skeleton of a function:

```
(define gen-hash-division-method (lambda (size)))
```

as well as:

```
(define hash-1 (gen-hash-division-method 701))
```

What I have coded:

```
(define gen-hash-division-method 
  (lambda (size)
   (lambda (w) 
    (modulo key(flip(w)) size))))
```

key(flip(w)) takes a list w and returns an integer.

And call:

```
(hash-1 '(h e l l o))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: (h e l l o) (no arguments)
```

Answer (score 6):

You're getting the error because in Scheme `(w)` expects `w` to be a function. But `w` is just a list of symbols.

In your case you have `key(flip(w))` which doesn't make sense in Scheme land.

*everything is surrounded by parentheses*

You want `(key (flip w))`

Remember the lisp mantra : `(function args ...)`